# Cannot run mysql command lines via Java on Amazon EC2. Docker app that works locally only

Tags: java, mysql, bash, docker, amazon-ec2

**Java code** that executres a mysql command to restore a datatbase from a sql file. This works locally on my machine but when I push my container to Amazon EC2, I run into an error.

```
restoreCmd = new String[]{"mysql ","--user="+doc.getDatabaseUserName(), "--password="+doc.getDatabasePass(),"--host="+doc.getDatabaseHostUri(),"-e","source " + file.getAbsolutePath()};
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(restoreCmd);
            System.out.println("Inserted into RDS");
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Error** that comes up in on amazon. I had this error locally when I had the mysql bin path wrong. I fixed that and it worked locally but when I build this app as a docker container I run into the same issues as if the program can't find mysql after its installed via docker?

```


13:40:27
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysql ": error=2, No such file or directory
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysql ": error=2, No such file or directory
```

**Docker File** that Installs mysql server and client .

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk

ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.5.0
ARG USER_HOME_DIR="/root"
ARG SHA=beb91419245395bd69a4a6edad5ca3ec1a8b64e41457672dc687c173a495f034
ARG BASE_URL=https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/${MAVEN_VERSION}/binaries

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref \
  && curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz ${BASE_URL}/apache-maven-${MAVEN_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz \
  && echo "${SHA}  /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c - \
  && tar -xzf /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz -C /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
  && rm -f /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz \
  && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install mysql-server
RUN apt-get -y install mysql-client
RUN service mysql start


ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"

COPY mvn-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh
COPY settings-docker.xml /usr/share/maven/ref/
COPY . /usr/local/BigData
VOLUME "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Why do you want to run **mysql** command line client? Why do not use **JDBC** from Java to run the script?

Comment: I am new to mysql in general , i used this command. The idea is that my application takes a .sql file and import it to an exsisting database xyz that I already have. Does JDBC have an import command like the one I use here?

Comment: Can you not use the full path to the mysql executable?

Comment: JDBC cannot import files, but you can load the script file as a `String` and you can run it thru JDBC on the database server...

Comment: @RamanSailopal thats the thing, i'm really not sure where the mysql/bin file is in the file directory once it is installed via docker on EC2. When i did this locally i could easily just look in my file system and go c:/users/john/...../mysql and put the path in where it says "mysql" on that command line.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto Is this what your kind of talking about? Using a file reader to read the sql file then do the "importing"  .  http://java.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/java-l/running-an-sql-file-from-java-via-jdbc-api-1408498

Comment: I am rather astonished you managed to build a docker image that runs locally but not on the target environment. Especially the message `Cannot run program "mysql ": error=2` should both appear on your local system as on the target host. Please recheck running the image with `docker run` locally.

Comment: C:/ ??? So this is Bash on Windows?

Comment: Yes bash, I plugged in C:/ locally to make it work on my windows computer which has mysql. On amazons ec2 they use linux so all my of docker commands and file paths are bash related. When i do the command RUN apt-get install mysql-server in my docker file i'm not sure where it installs it too on the ec2 machine, like the file path to /mysql

Comment: @JohnHanewich Yes, something like that...